# FrontRow or App like FrontRow on Lion

Tags: macos, front-row

Is FrontRow available for Mac OS X Lion or is there some third party app which does roughly the same?

I particular like about FrontRow being able to use it with my Mac Remote and I love to watch trailers / dvds. iTunes integration is not that much of importance to me, but would be a nice to have.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either try to get Front Row running on Lion, or try **Plex**.

- Front Row was discontinued in OS X Lion; that’s probably why you can’t find it. That said, there’s nothing to stop you running it, if you don’t mind a few limitations. Ralph Perdomo has some instructions for Front Row on Lion (http://www.mac-hatter.com/blog/frontrowenablerforlion), although they require you to stay on iTunes 10.3, which doesn’t work with some iOS devices. If you’re really attached to Front Row, this probably works, but I haven’t tried it.
- Plex (http://www.plexapp.com/mac.php) also seems pretty decent; I know a lot of people who use it and are very happy with it. Sort of like Front Row, but it pulls content from lots of other places, including iTunes. [This support page](http://wiki.plexapp.com/index.php/Apple_Remote) suggests that they support the Apple Remote, as you wanted. You might like to check that one out.

Comment: Running Front Row on Lion doesn't *require* iTunes 10.3. The older version of iTunes simply doesn't break the music component (i.e., playing songs through Front Row). You can run it using the latest iTunes, but simply won't be able to play songs. So as @scravy is saying it's not that much of a concern, he shouldn't have any problems ported Snow Leopard's Front Row to Lion.

Comment: No problem. I'm running it just fine under Lion with the latest iTunes. Works perfect for watching videos or Apple trailers, just as it did in Snow Leopard. The only thing missing is the ability to play music.

Comment: I simply copy a SL FrontRow to my Lion machine?!

Comment: There are a couple of other files as well, I think. See Ralph Perdomo’s instructions.

Comment: Worth to mention [plex is done](http://www.plexapp.com/credits.php) with [xbmc](http://xbmc.org) and, if you want more customization, that's the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend Plex for this - I use it to play movies and music off my Pro, via gigabit, to an old MBP connected to a 40" LCD.

I can confirm it uses the Apple Remote, and works really, really well.